# MVC 3 IoC Container Causes both Client and Server Validation Problems

Tags: inversion-of-control, asp.net-mvc-3

We have recently upgraded a project to MVC 3 Tools and discovered that our inversion of control container is causing problems with the native MVC model binding validation on both client- and server-side. When we have the IoC hooked up the client validation fails to fire at all and the "IsValid" test in the controller fires erratically and passes along data when it should not.

The only way we've been able to correct the validation framework is to disable the IoC completely. We were using Ninject when the issue first arose but we've also tried StructureMap and Unity and encountered the exact same behavior. We're thinking the issue may reside in IDependencyResolver itself, but that is just a guess. We've also tried disabling all 3rd party tools (Telerik) but the issue seems to only be in the IoC.

My questions for the community:  has anybody else experienced validation problems when using IoC in MVC? I would be most grateful for any guidance on this issue. Many thanks.

Comment: I've not seen this type of issue, but I was just curious if you ever discovered what was causing it in your environment.

Comment: Turns out the issue was generated from the CTP version of Entity Framework/Code First. IoC worked as expected when we were able to upgrade to the 4.1 release.